# In order to move my question to a different Q&A site, should I delete my topic and ask a new question?

Tags: discussion, migration

I asked a question on Super User, and now I think it may be better suited for Ask Ubuntu. Should I delete it and ask a new question on Ask Ubuntu? Or ask someone to do this for me? Or just leave it there and ask it again on Ask Ubuntu?

Comment: When a question is about a specific question on a site, it is better to ask it on the site Meta instead of here. Just FYR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you didn't receive an answer yet, you can delete the post. There is no need for a moderator to get involved. You can ask the question on the other site after deletion.

If your question has received answers, you shouldn't delete it unless the quality of the answers is really bad. If you have a positive-scoring answer you can't even delete it. Then you should flag a moderator to migrate it, or leave it on the site you originally posted it.